# Zend Framework in a subfolder, but images taken from site root

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a dev project setup in a subfolder on my testing machine and it must stay there. 
However all the Zend frameworks views are linked to server root.

CSS are linked like:

```
<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('/css/frontend.css') ?>" rel="Stylesheet" />
```

Which must be stayed this way, but it should link to

```
localhost/a/b/c/prj1/css/frontend.css
```

How can I setup a global subdirectory for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add
`resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/a/b/c/prj1"`
to your configuration.
This will set the baseurl wher to link to.

Be aware the `$this->headLink()` helper isn't aware of the baseUrl (probably bcs of bc).
To make it work use either:
`$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('/css/frontend.css'));` or
`$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'css/frontend.css');`
depending on what you feel more comfortable with

**Edit:**
updated according to comments

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't worked out, I've added to the ini file, and the above CSS resource is still not linked properly, but the a href tags are.

Comment: thats really strange, you say in the same file two calls to `$this->baseUrl()` return different results?

Comment: The problem raises now when I use `appendStylesheet` in a Plugin Abstract with `echo $this->headLink()`. At that moment the CSS is added without subfolder reference, like this: `$view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/' . $moduleName . '.css', 'screen');` but when this gets printed does not use the baseUrl. Why?

Comment: The implementation of the HeadLink-helper isn't baseUrl aware. you could work around this by doing `$this->HeadLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('/css/' . $moduleName . '.css'), 'screen');`

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if i understand it clearly but try to :

if you are on linux :
don't edit the code and `symlink` to folder `/images/` to `/a/b/c/prj1/images/`

**update**

form your comments with samual :

you can use something like :

```
    <?php
    $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl("css/reset.css"))
            ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl("css/text.css"))
            ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl("css/960.css"))
            ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl("css/demo.css"));
    echo $this->headLink();
    ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not on linux, and do not want this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want it in a subdirectory of your project?

Your landing page when going to the url should point to the public folder. This is were all css/js/images should be placed. Your other project files should be set with the right permissions for security.

Of course it's possible to set the css folder with different security settings because it's in your project folder but I don't see the point of doing it that way.

Comment: As I mentioned it's a dev setup problem.