# Running a CFWheels site from a subfolder instead of the web root

Tags: frameworks, coldfusion, cfwheels

My CFWheels site is running under subfolder/ in the web root, and I have the web.config on the same level as subfolder/. In my web.config I have the necessary URL rewrite rule to remove "subfolder/index.cfm/" from the URL.

My problem arises when I try to include a Javascript file from the default "javascripts" folder using

```
javaScriptIncludeTag("script.js")
```

By default, cfwheels looks in /subfolder/javascripts/ for the JS file. However, I've removed subfolder/ from the URL, so a request to /subfolder/javascripts/script.js fails with the following error message:

> Wheels.ViewNotFound
>
> Could not find the view page for the javascripts action in the subfolder controller.

Bogus. "javascripts" and "subfolder" are not an action and a controller.

I believe a request to /javscripts/script.js would succeed. How do I tell cfwheels not to look for the javascripts/ folder in subfolder/?

I was unable to find the answer in the documentation, and I haven't gotten any response on the CFWheels Google Group either. I'm looking for an answer [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646000/zend-framework-in-a-subfolder-but-images-taken-from-site-root/4646357#4646357), but specific to CFWheels.

**edit**
IIS 7 web.config rewrite:

```
<rule name="Remove subfolder/index.cfm">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/subfolder/index.cfm/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

My problem may be here if this rule is incorrect, I'm not sure.

linkTo() actually links to the incorrect path as well.

```
linkTo(text="Say Hello", controller="say", action="hello")
```

outputs

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/subfolder/index.cfm/say/hello">Say Hello</a>
```

Comment: Can you post your URL rewrite file? Are you rewriting to rewrite.cfm? Are calls to linkTo() and such writing the correct URLs?

Comment: I am not rewriting to rewrite.cfm as the documentation doesn't mention it in regards to IIS 7. I've updated the question with the rewrite rule and the output of linkTo().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is that you are forgetting to negate the javascript and other folders for cfwheels.

i did i writeup the covered this a while back:

http://rip747.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/cfwheels-url-rewriting-in-a-subfolder/

though this was for a different url rewriter i'm sure you could port the rules to IIS7.

Comment: Ah, so it appears that I should be rewriting to `/subfolder/rewrite.cfm/{R:1}` instead of `/subfolder/index.cfm/{R:1}` (I was wondering what rewrite.cfm was for.) Even after this change, however, linkTo() still generates `http://mysite/subfolder/say/hello`. How do I now remove subfolder from the URL?

Comment: Ok, I see now that the default "ColdFusion on Wheels URL Rewriting" rule should do all of the rewriting I need, it just needs to be enabled. This was an oversight on my part, but the site runs great now. However, I would still like to remove `subfolder/` from the URL. Can that be done?

Comment: @Riley I think that you would need to configure the server to support multiple sites, then map each site to its dir i.e. site one would go to wwwroot/subfolder1 This way you can directly access the site without "subfolder1" in the url